# How to install different libtorrent version for python3-libtorrent

Tags: deluge

I am using deluge which comes with python3-liborrent. Currently deluge 2.1.1 with libtorrent 1.2.16.
Nevertheless I need to use liborrent 1.2.15.

I was unable to find any guide in order to do so. What I can see is that when python3-libtorrent is installed the daily-repo is used and 1.2.16 is installed.

I downloaded libtorrent directly and compiled it successfully, nevertheless it is not used by deluge.

Would you have any advice in which direction I can proceed?

I am running 20.04